# How to get count on ths query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, subquery

I'm doing an

```
INSERT INTO table1...  
   SELECT...  
   FROM table2
```

However, I need to retrieve the identity from a table3 and do an insert into it just before inserting into table1.  These two inserts need to occur together, with table3 insert going first.  I've tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)  
   SELECT (  
      col1=(insert into table3(col1, col2)values(1,1) select SCOPE_IDENTITY(),   
      col2, col3)  
   FROM table2
```

But that doesn't work.  table1.col1 does need the identity value from the new insert into table3.  Amount of data to insert probably no more than a few 100 rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: How much data are we talking about for these inserts?

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you give a little more detail on the exact columns in each table.  Without knowing what goes into table3, it's hard to say whether the best approach is iterating or making it set-based.

Comment: I suggest you wrapped all your `INSERT`s on a transaction an then retrieve the identitys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to use the [Output Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @MyResults table(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

INSERT INTO table3 (col1, col2)
    OUTPUT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), table2.col2, table2.col3 INTO @MyResults
SELECT 1, 1 FROM table2

INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM @MyResults

COMMIT
```

Comment: The first part looks close.  For the 2nd part, table2 doesn't get any inserts.  table2 inserts into table1, using the ident from table3 as the value for table1.col1.  For insert into table1, maybe a join between @MyResults and table2?

Comment: Oops, I have changed it to insert into table1 at the bottom. Does that look any better?

Comment: Yes but the insert into table1 is missing data from table2.  table1 gets nearly all its data from table2...except the ident coming from @MyResults.

Comment: Maybe that will do it? I changed it so that col2 and col3 from table2 along with the generated id are inserted into the table variable, so they can be inserted into table 1 at the end.

Comment: What does it mean if there are no errors but no inserts into table3 and no ident values in @MyResults?  The other values are in @MyResults but ident values are null.  table2 does have values.

Comment: Interesting...I opened a new query window, pasted my query into it and now it inserts.   Identity values still null though.  Changed that to INSERTED.indentid and get the values that way.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use a combination of MERGE and OUTPUT. I think that is the best way.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using sql server 2005 (i.e., no MERGE).